# Creating custom shape using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Can anybody tell me is it possible to make a shape (like attached image) only using CSS.

This is shape -

[image]

I tried to archive this using `css` `border-radius` then it was close. But bottom of the shape it's wide is need to increase little. (see the image)

This is my code so far -

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="" >content</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
.content .nav-tabs {
  background: #dd5b5b;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .nav-tabs > li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.content .nav-tabs > li > a {
  padding: 5px 40px 10px;
  background: #eaedf2;
  border: 1px solid #a48686;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 2em;
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
}
```

[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/kuxeteca/1/edit?html,css,output)

It would be highly appreciated if someone can tell my how I figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below code.

```css
.content .nav-tabs {
  background: #dd5b5b;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .nav-tabs>li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.content .nav-tabs>li>a {
  padding: 5px 40px 10px;
  background: #eaedf2;
  border: 1px solid #a48686;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.content .nav-tabs>li>a:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  top: -2px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #eaedf2;
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  border: 1px solid #a48686;
  border-left: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content .nav-tabs>li>a:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  top: -2px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #eaedf2;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  border: 1px solid #a48686;
  border-right: none;
}

.content .nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">content</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">content2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">content2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">content2</a></li>
  </ul>



</div>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Comment: Its great.. But one thing, Can we change the order of list items. That mean you have done it from right to left. Can we change it to left to right?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like shown in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wPb8E/2/).

**HTML:** (Updated based on your mark-up)

```
<div class='content'>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active tabHdr"><a href="">content</a></li>
        <li class='tabHdr'><a href="#">content</a></li>
        <li class='tabHdr'><a href="#">content</a></li>
        <li class='tabHdr'><a href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:** (requires CSS3)

```
.content .nav-tabs {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #dd5b5b;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content .nav-tabs > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    top: 9px;
}
.tabHdr {
    position: relative;
    padding: 2% 2.5%;
    margin: 0% -1%;
}
.tabHdr::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0.25em;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(25px) rotateX(10deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(25px) rotateX(10deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(25px) rotateX(10deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(25px) rotateX(10deg);
    transform: perspective(25px) rotateX(10deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    background-color: #eaedf2;
    border-width: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
    border-color: #a48686;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: gray;
}
.active{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Update:** [**Full Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wPb8E/7/)

Answer (score 1):

I got the tab's shape using CSS `border-radius` and pseudo-elements:

```
.content .nav-tabs > li > a {
  padding: 5px 40px 10px;
  background: #eaedf2;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-top-right-radius: 14px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.content .nav-tabs > li > a:before,
.content .nav-tabs > li > a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid #eaedf2;
}

.content .nav-tabs > li > a:before {
  left: -7px;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

.content .nav-tabs > li > a:after {
  right: -7px;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a border around tab?

Comment: @TNK yes but the border will not be applied to the pseuso-elements, so the slanting-sides of the tabs will still not have a border.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean by "the bottom is too wide", but have you tried to use margins?

margin-left: 5px;
This seems to be closer to your picture, though still a bit too rounded.

Answer (score 0):

[`border-radius` can take 1 or 2 values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius), with one value it has a circular radius , with two you can define a elliptical radius.

So you just need to change your radius definitions, like so:

```
border-top-right-radius: 1em 3em;
border-top-left-radius: 1em 3em;
```

Heres what it looks like, but [you can preview it on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cv7df/) Now you just need to figure out what radii will work best for your design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

```
.content .nav-tabs > li:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 18px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #eaedf2;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.content .nav-tabs > li:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 18px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #eaedf2;
  -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}
```

Just mess around with the values to get the incline you need!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/q29X5/1/

Here's a fiddle, it took me a while and the code is a bit messy but you'll figure it out.

CSS:

```
.tabBar {
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f55, #d33);
    height:50px;
}
.tabOut {
    display:block-inline;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
    width:100px;
    /*transform perspective*/
    -webkit-perspective:150px;
    perspective:150px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin:50% 50%;
    perspective-origin:50% 50%;
}
.tabIn {
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #dcdcdc);
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-color:#333 #333 transparent #333;
    /*transforms*/
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(45deg)translate(0px, 2px);
    -webkit-perspective:150px;
    perspective:150px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin:50% 50%;
    perspective-origin:50% 50%;
}
.tabIn .tabText {
    font-size:40px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    /*Transform*/
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(-30deg)scale(0.5, 0.8);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabBar">
        <div class="tabOut">
            <div class="tabIn"> <span class="tabText">Tab1</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabOut">
            <div class="tabIn"> <span class="tabText">Tab2</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabOut">
            <div class="tabIn"> <span class="tabText">Tab3</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

1(one)Tab:

```
        <div class="tabOut">
            <div class="tabIn"> <span class="tabText">I'm a tab</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabOut">
```